# How to delete substring from a list and have a full string of it present in list?

Tags: python-3.x, substring

I have a python list having many sub-strings of a full string including the full string. Can someone help me to remove all the sub-strings from the list and have only full string.

```
lists = ['ab','bcd','cd','abcd','ef']
```

For the above input, i want the output to be as:

```
lists = ['abcd','ef']
```

Please note, not to consider the string length from this example since my actual list items length is much fluctuating.

Answer (score 1):

This is not python code, but my algorithm. Hope it works

Let have 2 arrays, `array1` for input and `array2` for result

1. Find longest length element in array
2. For each element in `array1`, check with shorter elements:

   - if included [duplicate] -> Remove
   - if not keep
   - Add this long element in new `array2` and
     remove from `array1`
3. For those kept elements

   - Do step 2 again until finish
   - if only 1 element left in `array1`
     . just add it to `array2`

Answer (score 0):

```
import copy
listA = ['abc','bcd','abcd', 'ef', 'eef']
listB=copy.deepcopy(listA) # create 2nd copy of main list 
new_list=[]
global longest_str
longest_str=max(listA, key=len)
l_len=len(listA)
while l_len>0:
    for l in listB:
        if l in longest_str and len(l)<len(longest_str):
            listA.remove(l)  # remove the sub-string
        if longest_str == l:  
            new_list.append(l) #append longest string in new_list
            listA.remove(l) #remove from the main list 
    l_len=len(listA)
    if l_len>0:
        longest_str=max(listA, key=len)

print(new_list)
```